# How to find the coordinates of vectors in the Taylor basis?

Tags: vector-spaces

I want to find the coordinates of these vectors in the Taylor basis centered at a point of $x_0=1$:

$$
a=x^2+2x-1
$$
$$
b=4x^2+2x+5
$$

I've represented my vectors in the Taylor basis as follows (I hope, I'm not mistaken):
$$
a,b=\{1;(x-1);(x-1)^2\}
$$

The issue arises on the last step, when I take $x-1$ as $t$, so my vectors will look accordingly: $a=t^2+4t+3$ and $b=4t^2+10t+11$.

I cannot figure out where to exactly go from here, how can I reduce this to the solution of, for example, $a=(2;4;1)$?

I will appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2+2 x-1=2+4 (x-1)+(x-1)^2$$
Coordinates are $(2,4,1)$
$$4 x^2 + 2 x + 5=11 + 10 (x-1) + 4 (x-1)^2$$
$(11,10,4)$ are its coordinate in the base $\left\{1;(x-1);(x-1)^2\right\}$

Comment: Thank you so much, still can't really figure out how does this Taylor basis work and for what purposes should I use it, but you've answered my question, and that's all that matters :)

Comment: @JoshJohnson I think it is just an exercise on Taylor formula which is one of the most useful tool in analysis. $\sin x\approx x$ for small $x$ is mind blowing, IMO